# What features are required in a touch screen monitor to work with Ubuntu?

Tags: touchscreen

I have a NUC (NUC6i3SYH) with Ubuntu 15.10 installed.

I'd like to hook it up to a touch screen monitor.

Touchscreen prices vary widely and there seem to be lots of specs/features to take into consideration.

What features are technical 'must haves' for a touch screen to get the most out of operating Ubuntu with touch?

I'd like to avoid buying a monitor based on price, only to find it lacks a required feature.

Edit:  To clarify, I'm not seeking recommendations for 'best monitor', but a list of the technical features required of a touchscreen monitor that will enable it to work with Ubuntu.

Comment: We generally do not make hardware recommendations. Test it wilt a live usb or search the screen on google + linux. My experience with touch screen is that the basic features work bu not all applications respond to gestures.